# Remove extra lines between imports with PHP CS Fixer

Tags: php, php-cs-fixer

Is there a rule to remove extra new lines inside import?

So change:

```php
use Foo\Bar\A;
use Foo\Bar\B;

use Foo\Bar\C;
use Foo\Bar\D;
```

To this:

```php
use Foo\Bar\A;
use Foo\Bar\B;
use Foo\Bar\C;
use Foo\Bar\D;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`no_extra_blank_lines` configuration](https://cs.symfony.com/doc/rules/whitespace/no_extra_blank_lines.html).

I added the following to my configuration to remove the extra lines between use statements.

```
'no_extra_blank_lines' => ['tokens' => ['use']]
```